# Home screen icons vanishing, and unable to restore some of them

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, home-screen-shortcuts

My Alcatel Onetouch idol 3 currently runs Android 6.0.1, since Alcatel doesn't launches updates, as of this version. At the opposite, it often updates its own "over-layer", and I suspect this part to be responsible of my problem, as follows.

From about a couple of months, I noted that some of my home screen icons had suddenly vanished. Then it continued later, some other icons vanishing at successive random times.
Note: not only alone icons but folders vanish as well.

So my first question:
**What may cause icons to vanish, and how to prevent it?**

Beyond that, I obviously wanted to recover them, and sure it was pretty simple, selecting them from the Apps drawer.
But... two apps (Gmail and Notes) doesn't appear any longer in Apps drawer, **although they keep showing through Params|Applications**!
So I can't restore this ones.

So my second question:
**How to make these icon go back to Apps drawer?**

Comment: Have you tried another launcher to check if it is affected by both problems (icons disappearing from home screen and drawer? If it is not, then the issue will be with the launcher. Clearing its cache and/or data might help; or simply using another launcher.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks for the idea, i'll do it, then wait and see... But in any case, how to recover missing apps in Apps drawer?